# Assigning plant taxa to functional groups in R

Tags: stacked-bar-chart, s

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot of the frequency of occurrence of plant taxa that belong to functional groups across different sites.

I am having trouble figuring out how to assign my plant taxa to functional groups. I have about 159 different plant taxa that I am trying to separate into 4 functional groups.

To be honest I am not quite sure where to even start.

I have looked into the tidyr workesheet but am not quite sure where to even start. I created a character vector with the four functional groups. Not sure what are the best functions to use.